# Warning: log() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in

Tags: php

I'm getting this PHP warning: Warning: log() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in (route to this file)

I don't know why... I'm not declaring the type of the variable. Any help?

Here's the code:

```
    function sanitizeMysql ($string, $mysqli) {

        return $mysqli->real_escape_string($string);

    }

    function sanitizeHtml ($string) {

        return htmlspecialchars($string);

    }

    function log ($data, $mysqli) {

        $data = sanitizeMysql($data, $mysqli);
        $data = sanitizeHtml($data);

        if ($insert = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO log (data) VALUES ('" . $data . "')")) {

            if ($insert->execute()) {

                return $mysqli->insert_id;

            } else {

                return $mysqli->error;

            }

        }  else {

            return $mysqli->error;

        }

    }

$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$error = "Unauthorized view of ". $url;
log($error, $mysqli);
exit();
```

$mysqli is declared and working. Any idea?

Comment: It's probably calling a mathematical `log` function for some reason. Is this the real code? What happens if you change the name?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php < surprised you're not getting a `cannot redeclare function` error...

Comment: Your sanitizing is not sufficient. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: @AlexHowansky give me an example of an attack to this code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to rename your custom function `log()`. Instead of `log()` , use a different name for your function.

`log()` is an (*already existing*) mathematical function.

[Read about `log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php)

Best of luck!

Comment: He redefined `log`

Answer (score 5):

Log is already a function in PHP, just rename it to something else

http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php

Answer (score -1):

I guess the right log function that you want use is 'error_log'. 'log' only is natural logarithm.

Error log: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-log.php

Natural logarithm: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.log.php